# Putting a max-width and aligning text in the middle of parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In one of my row's I'd like to put a max width and center my text within that div.

**My homepage text currently looks like:**:

[image: Current]

I'd like to put a max width and center the text within this one section.

**Ideal outcome:**

[image: Desired outcome]

**CSS**

```
.homepage-text {
    font-size: 130%;
}

.light-section {
      background-color: lightblue;
    /* color: white; */
        text-align: center:
    }
```

**HTML**

```
      <div class="row light-section">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12 homepage-text">

<p>Text sit's here</p>
</div></div></div>
```

**Live Link:** http://185.123.97.138/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand exactly what did you mean, but try this:

```
.homepage-text {
    font-size: 130%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
.homepage-text {
    font-size: 130%;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    float: none;
}
```

I've set a fixed `width` of `960px` instead of a fluid `width` of `100%` and center this container with `margin: auto;`
Also, you have to unset the `float` property to make the `margin: auto;` works.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content in a fixed `width` or a maxed width `max-width` div, then make it `float:none;` and set the right and left margins `auto !important`

```
<div class="row light-section">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-12 homepage-text" style="width: 400px; float: none;margin: 0 auto !important;">

<p>Text sit's here</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also pull this off using dynamic margin & width values, without altering the float nor using `margin: 0 auto;` (If you want to use that margin, you will have to use `float: none;` Otherwise, it won't automatically center the homepage-text.)

```
.homepage-text {
    font-size: 130%;
    margin: 0 25% 0 25%; // Same as margin: 0 25%; but it illustrates 25+25+50=100%
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has already done that job for you. All you need to set is the max-width of the container class. Doing so helps to maintain consistency in the page layout. [Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/a3qqaveo/)

```css
.container {
  max-width:700px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
  <p>Text sit's here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```